# In UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer what is the use case for the 'edges=UIRectEdge.all' ?

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

From Apple APIs (see below):

1. The UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer has property edges of type
   UIRectEdge
2. UIRectEdge have property: [top, left, right, bottom, all]

I would think the purpose of UIRectEdge.all is to include all other four directions. 
But from my test (read below),  .all  didn't detect any directions at all.

```
//  UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.h
//  Copyright (c) 2012-2015 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
//

/*! This subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer only recognizes if the user slides their finger
in from the bezel on the specified edge. */
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    open class UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer {

    open var edges: UIRectEdge //< The edges on which this gesture recognizes, relative to the current interface orientation
}
```

Official UIRectEdge struct:

```
public struct UIRectEdge : OptionSet {
    public init(rawValue: UInt)

    public static var top: UIRectEdge { get }
    public static var left: UIRectEdge { get }
    public static var bottom: UIRectEdge { get }
    public static var right: UIRectEdge { get }
    public static var all: UIRectEdge { get }
}
```

But the edge detection didn't work to detect  'ANY' edge direction when we set edges= UIRectEdge.all

i.e. nothing will be detected 
( instead of 4 directions detection, none of the direction could be detected)
when using this code:

```
let myEdgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
myEdgePan.edges = UIRectEdge.all
myEdgePan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
myEdgePan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
myEdgePan.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myEdgePanned(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(coolEdgePan)
```

Instead I need the following workaround to detect all 4 edge Pan directions:

```
let edges : [UIRectEdge] = [.left, .right, .top, .bottom]

for edge in edges {
    let myEdgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
    myEdgePan.edges = edge
    myEdgePan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    myEdgePan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    myEdgePan.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.myEdgePanned(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(coolEdgePan)
    }
```

Anybody knows what is the use case for the 'UIRectEdge.all' ?